# Invoke AWS Lambda through web browser or CURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to invoke lambda function using web browser but nothing happens and nothing in the zabbix server logs. It works fine within lambda Test function and the data is sent to zabbix server. Any idea how I can invoke lambda with URI query parameters through web browser? I've created the API gateway trigger and that's the URL I'm trying to invoke as shown below.

`https://somename.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/default/Zabbix?Host=Zabbix%20server&key=lambda.test&Value=1.7`

This works fine but not http request directly through web browser.

[image]

Comment: A public api gateway endpoint will return just fine from a browser.  Perhaps there is a problem with your APIG setup.  Suggestion to narrow down the problem:  [test](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-test-method.html) the REST endpoint in the Api Gateway console.   It would be helpful to answerers if you pasted the browser error response in your question.

Comment: Did u find any logs in cloudwatch?